# How to load balance Http traffic based on url

Tags: java, http, httpserver

We use a cluster of [HttpServers (bundled with java)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) to handle http requests. Some percentage of our traffic is critical. We classify our http traffic as critical and non-critical based on some request parameters.

We want to dedicate some http servers for critical traffic. What is the best way to identify http request as critical/non-critical and route the request to appropriate server ?

1. Is it possible to route the http request to appropriate server without informing the caller (who invoked http request).
2. I know that we can redirect caller with http 3xx response code. Caller has to make another call - is it possible to do avoid this ?

Comment: Critical in what sense? Critical to me are resources that are most needed, and that u can simply measure and report as your server usage.

Comment: Critical means important from our usecase perspective. They may not consume heavy system resources. We want to ensure that spike in non-critical traffic should not impact critical traffic.

Comment: From my perspective you only have the choice between using different server-names for critical/non-critical traffic or using a load-balancer that allows to specify rules for routing.

Comment: Is it possible to configure rules based on http request parameters in load-balancer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most firewalls/loadbalancers will allow you to inspect traffic and route accordingly. We do this with an F5 and route HTTP traffic to pools of servers based upon specific HTTP headers using irules: https://devcentral.f5.com/irules

If that is not an option you always setup a loadbalancer, such as nginx (http://nginx.org/en/#basic_http_features), and use your URL pathing for prioritization. For example, all call the `http://domain.com/api` get routed to a set of servers while `http://domain.com/static` go to another.